# Real part of a complex function

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed linear complex vector space. If $u$ is the real part of the complex-linear functional $f$ on $V$, then $f(x) = u(x)-iu(ix)$ and $\|f\| = \|u\|$.

In the proof, there is one part which says that there exists a complex number $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| = 1$ such that

$$|f(x)| = \alpha f(x) = f(\alpha x) = u(\alpha x).$$

Why is $f(\alpha x) = u(\alpha x)$?

Answer (score 2):

As $f(\alpha x) = |f(x)|$, $f(\alpha x)$ is real, so it is equal to its real part. That is, $f(\alpha x) = u(\alpha x)$.